# Array key names start with specific name in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, key

How to get key names from array in a collection which is start from specific name;

```
var regExp=/specific name of key/

var cur = db.collectionName.find();
cur.forEach(function(doc)
{{ Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(key)
    {return key.match(regExp)})}}

var allKeys = {};
var regExp=/Alar/
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(doc){Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(key){allKeys[key]=1})});
allKeys;
```

with above code output ;

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : 1,
    "Name" : 1,
    "device_type" : 1,
    "grammerData" : 1,
    "code" : 1,
    "Command" : 1,
    "description" : 1,
    "created_by" : 1,
    "last_updated_time" : 1
}
now i want some script from which i can find those keys which start with specific name.
```

Its not working properly ,please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform regex search in mongodb like the following:

```
db.collectionname.find({field:/abc/},function(err,data) {
  //your code
}
```

This will search for all the documents that starts with **abc**. If you wanna search from more than one regex, you can use the `$in` operator to search for values inside an array:

```
db.collectionName.find({field:{$in:[/abc/,/what/]}},function(err,data){
    //your code
}
```

This will return all the documents in which the field "field" starts with **abc** or **what**

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: i want only key names?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: var allKeys = {};
db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(doc){Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(key){allKeys[key]=1})});
allKeys;
with this i can see keys names,now i want thode key name which start with specific name?

Comment: Please, think a bit and formulate a better question. I am trying to help you but I really don't understand what you want.